# KivyMD MDBoxLayout Alignment Issue

Tags: python-3.x, layout, alignment, kivymd

In an `MDBoxLayout`, I am attempting to align 4 widgets.

Here is my code for the layout:

```
class MusicPlayer(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, file):
        super().__init__(orientation='horizontal', spacing=10, padding=5, size_hint_y=None)
        
        self.file = file

        self.progress_bar = MDSlider(min=0, max=100, show_off=False)
        self.elapsed_label = MDLabel(text='0:00', size_hint_x=0.2)
        self.remaining_label = MDLabel(text='0:00', size_hint_x=0.2)

        self.add_widget(MDIconButton(icon='play', on_press=self.play_pause))
        self.add_widget(self.elapsed_label)
        self.add_widget(self.progress_bar)
        self.add_widget(self.remaining_label)

    def play_pause(self, button):
        button.icon = 'pause' if button.icon == 'play' else 'play'
```

And here is the result:


[image: Layout result]


As you can see, the `MDIconButton` is not aligned with the rest of the widgets, and the first MDLabel is slightly higher than the rest of the widgets. Any help to align these widgets would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MusicPlayer(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.spacing = 10
        self.padding = 5
        self.size_hint_y = None
        self.md_bg_color = (0, 1, 1, 0.3)

        self.progress_bar = MDSlider(min=0, max=100, show_off=False)

        self.elapsed_label = MDLabel(text='0:00', pos_hint={"center_y": 0.5}, size_hint=(None, None))
        self.elapsed_label.text_size = (None, None)
        self.elapsed_label.height = self.elapsed_label.texture_size[1]

        self.remaining_label = MDLabel(text='0:00', pos_hint={"center_y": 0.5}, size_hint=(None, None))
        self.remaining_label.text_size = (None, None)
        self.remaining_label.height = self.remaining_label.texture_size[1]

        self.add_widget(MDIconButton(icon='play', pos_hint={"center_y": 0.5}))
        self.add_widget(self.elapsed_label)
        self.add_widget(self.progress_bar)
        self.add_widget(self.remaining_label)
```

[image]